# CSS/HTML Text Move on Hover and Display Additional Text

Tags: html, css, text, hover

So I have this container box that I want the link at the bottom left corner to move slightly up on hover to reveal more, smaller text underneath!
I have a link included that has an example of what I'm trying to do. Sorry if some of the CSS is a jumbled mess, just got back into it and kinda learning as I go. I have thoroughly researched and sought after an answer. Even if you can just link me to page that will help I'd be super grateful.

[Website Here](http://method.gg)

[JSFiddle I have So far](https://jsfiddle.net/chjam97q/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="body_paragraph">
    <div class="body_container">
        <h3><a href="progress">This is the Link</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.body_paragraph{
    background-color: #222;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    padding: 2px;
    min-height: 500px;

}

.body_container h3{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 10px;
}

.body_container h3 a{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body_container h3 a:hover{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #009dff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body_container{
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    width: 998px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    min-height: 299px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #111;
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: Isn't font size supposed to be 14px and not just 14?

Comment: @VarshaDhadge Haha Yes, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".link").hover(function() {
     $(".text-info").html("Some texts here.");
    }, function() {
      $(".text-info").html("");
});
```

```css
.body_container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80px;
}
a {
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
a:hover {
  padding-top: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="body_paragraph">
    <div class="body_container">
        <a href="progress" class="link"><h3>This is the Link</h3></a>
        <div class="text-info"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it something you're wanting to move toward?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I am looking for! Sorry, I had no idea it was JS most likely doing what I need! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

youse this code

`.body_container h3 a:hover{
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  display:block;
}`

you can change the value of -10px

Comment: I want the bottom, left link to move up slightly to reveal more text when I hover over it. Such a date and time and name

Comment: This is pretty close! Thank you for doing this! I will definitely bookmark this to add on to later on!

Answer (score 0):

The way your example website has done is that they first made **opacity** of the underneath text as **0** and then gave it the **negative margin** so that the main text and the underneath text can overlap. But remember due to **opacity** as **0** underneath text will not be visible right now. So when you **hover the main text** you can **remove the negative margin and make opacity as 1 of the underneath element**. This is how example website given by you is doing this thing. **No javascript is required for this**.